# Singing the Mishna: sources

Tags: sources-mekorot, music, mishna

I remember seeing once in (I think) Tiferet Yisrael that every mishna had its own distinctive melody. Does anybody know where he said that, or (if it wasn't Tiferet Yisrael) which mishnaic commentator made that observation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See Tiferet Yisrael on [Arachin 4, 1 (Boaz)](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/mishkods/mishkods13.pdf):

> שהיו להן זמירות מיוחדין לכל משנה ומשנה

He says this helped them memorize the *mishnayot*. See also [here](http://forum.otzar.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=8063&p=71772&hilit=%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%92%D7%95%D7%9F%20%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94) for several more sources for a special *nigun* for Mishnah (the [Shlah](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=5s9kAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT378&lpg=PT378&dq=%22%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%20%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A8%20%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90%20%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94%22&source=bl&ots=QWto8xGdCw&sig=MT1C7Y_D03Rly3-0ZldfjlymfYQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiG1qXt2dvLAhUILZoKHT9VBBQQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%22%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%20%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A8%20%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90%20%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94%22&f=false) mentioned in the first post is similar, etc.).